# Is Azure AD suitable for a public network of apps?

Tags: entra-id, single-sign-on

We are currently using Office 365 with Azure AD to manage our user management (currently about 100 users and 20 groups) in the AD. Our semi-public apps are currently using either a 3rd party user management system and some are still using no centralized management for users.

We are aiming for releasing some apps to the public in the following year and want to use a centralized way of managing users, permissions, etc... to have Users, passwords and permissions synced in an SSO environment.

Some people I asked before about this asked why we are not using our current AD and just have a 3rd party System like Auth0 handle everything. My question is now, is it suitable to have a combination of both (AD and a 3rd party management) or should we only use a 3rd party system?

Answer (score 1):

For sure Azure AD is suitable. You should connect every application to Azure AD using oauth2. We have done it for many applications.
That means centralized management in Azure AD, centralized security (for example apply conditional access for all third party applications) and just one password (or even passwordless) to manage.